# Nested if issue. The final plot just shows the plot in blue color. what could be going wrong?

Tags: pine-script, nested-if

'''

```
//@version=4
study( "testing nested if")
// Update 'plotColour' variable
plotColour = if close > open
    color.red
    if close > close[1]
        color.blue
plot(close, color=plotColour, linewidth=2)
```

'''

The final plot just shows the plot in blue color. what could be going wrong ?

Comment: Could you be more specific about the language you're using and elaborate on the context of your problem?

Comment: I am using PineScript. While learning pinescript  on Kodify, I came across nested-if. I copy pasted the code to see the results . But It was not working. I want that the color of the plot to variate between red ( when only one condition is met ) and blue ( when both the conditions are met ) . But the plot shows up as blue color only.

Comment: no reply yet . Please help